# Problems implementing TinyMCE in CodeIgniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, tinymce, richtextbox, text-editor

I am trying to implement TinyMCE in CodeIgniter. I've created a view file and called it from a controller. I have uploaded all files into my CI project folder and showed the path of the files. But it is not working. Here is the view file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Full featured example</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<!-- TinyMCE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>application/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave,visualblocks",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft,visualblocks",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css : "<?php echo base_url()?>application/tinymce/examples/css/content.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "<?php echo base_url()?>application/tinymce/examples/lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "<?php echo base_url()?>application/tinymce/examples/lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "<?php echo base_url()?>application/tinymce/examples/lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "<?php echo base_url()?>application/tinymce/examples/lists/media_list.js",

        // Style formats
        style_formats : [
            {title : 'Bold text', inline : 'b'},
            {title : 'Red text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
            {title : 'Red header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
            {title : 'Example 1', inline : 'span', classes : 'example1'},
            {title : 'Example 2', inline : 'span', classes : 'example2'},
            {title : 'Table styles'},
            {title : 'Table row 1', selector : 'tr', classes : 'tablerow1'}
        ],

        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values : {
            username : "Some User",
            staffid : "991234"
        }
    });
</script>
<!-- /TinyMCE -->

</head>
<body role="application">

<form method="post" action="http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/dump.php?example=true">
    <div>
        <h3>Full featured example</h3>

        <p>
            This page shows all available buttons and plugins that are included in the TinyMCE core package.
            There are more examples on how to use TinyMCE in the <a href="http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/">Wiki</a>.
        </p>

        <!-- Gets replaced with TinyMCE, remember HTML in a textarea should be encoded -->
        <div>
            <textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%">
                &lt;p&gt;
                    This is some example text that you can edit inside the &lt;strong&gt;TinyMCE editor&lt;/strong&gt;.
                &lt;/p&gt;
                &lt;p&gt;
                Nam nisi elit, cursus in rhoncus sit amet, pulvinar laoreet leo. Nam sed lectus quam, ut sagittis tellus. Quisque dignissim mauris a augue rutrum tempor. Donec vitae purus nec massa vestibulum ornare sit amet id tellus. Nunc quam mauris, fermentum nec lacinia eget, sollicitudin nec ante. Aliquam molestie volutpat dapibus. Nunc interdum viverra sodales. Morbi laoreet pulvinar gravida. Quisque ut turpis sagittis nunc accumsan vehicula. Duis elementum congue ultrices. Cras faucibus feugiat arcu quis lacinia. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque fermentum magna sit amet tellus varius ullamcorper. Vestibulum at urna augue, eget varius neque. Fusce facilisis venenatis dapibus. Integer non sem at arcu euismod tempor nec sed nisl. Morbi ultricies, mauris ut ultricies adipiscing, felis odio condimentum massa, et luctus est nunc nec eros.
                &lt;/p&gt;
            </textarea>
        </div>

        <!-- Some integration calls -->
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="tinyMCE.get('elm1').show();return false;">[Show]</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="tinyMCE.get('elm1').hide();return false;">[Hide]</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="tinyMCE.get('elm1').execCommand('Bold');return false;">[Bold]</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="alert(tinyMCE.get('elm1').getContent());return false;">[Get contents]</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="alert(tinyMCE.get('elm1').selection.getContent());return false;">[Get selected HTML]</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="alert(tinyMCE.get('elm1').selection.getContent({format : 'text'}));return false;">[Get selected text]</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="alert(tinyMCE.get('elm1').selection.getNode().nodeName);return false;">[Get selected element]</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<b>Hello world!!</b>');return false;">[Insert HTML]</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="tinyMCE.execCommand('mceReplaceContent',false,'<b>{$selection}</b>');return false;">[Replace selection]</a>

        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" />
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
    </div>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "not working". Are you getting any errors? What, *exactly*, isn't working?

Comment: the text editor is no working. No CSS,jQuery effects are working.

Comment: is the way I showed the path of js and css files correct?

Answer (score 1):

[You are not allowed to call a file within the `application` folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427414/access-forbidden-to-view-image-file-located-in-codeigniter-view-foldr/18427549#18427549), take a look at `.htaccess` file exists in application:

```
Deny from all
```

you'll get 403 error `Access forbidden!`

Anyway, this problem would no be resolved by disabling that line, because CodeIgniter looks at the URI and says: "Okay, I should call `application` class which exists in controller folder and then call the `tinymce` method by passing these arguments: `jscripts, tiny_mce, tiny_mce.js`".

So:

1. Put your files out of `application/` folder, somewhere like `public/` folder beside `index.php`.
2. Open `.htaccess` file which exists in the root, and add name of files/folders to prevent them from being passed through `index.php`.

For instance, considering this structure:

```
system/
application/
public/
      img/
      css/
      js/
.htaccess
index.php
robots.txt
```

The rewrite rules (`.htaccess`) should be:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|robots\.txt)
#                               |
#   Exclude the public folder <--
#   From being treated by:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Take a look at **[CodeIgniter User Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html)** for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure there is no js error in your project and also the path of js related to the editor is correct so the js can work for the editor.

Comment: there is no js error. because it is working well when I'm using it outside CI. is the way I showed the path of js and css files correct?