# CodeIgniter - Linking an exernal css not working

Tags: css, codeigniter

Here is the hierarchy of my files

```
Codeigniter/
   applications/
       assets/
           styles.css
       ...
       views/
           welcome.php

   system/
       ...
```

under my style.css is this code

```
p {
    color: #3333ff;
    background-color: #66ff66;
}
```

and under the welcome.php is this one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
     <p>test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I set my base_url as

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Codeigniter/';
```

I cant understand why the css file isn't working

I also tried to change link to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/assets/styles.css" />
```

but didn't work also

Comment: Are you testing this on a live, publicly available website, or locally?

Comment: i test it locally....

Comment: Can you paste code that comes to browser? (page source)
Sometimes debugging tools built in browser may help (I mean Dragonfly in Opera, Firebug in Firefox or Dev Tools in Chrome).

Comment: You forgot the 's' in applications.

Comment: This may clear WHY? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128740/problems-implementing-tinymce-in-codeigniter/12763788#12763788

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a similar local setup (XAMPP) and I have the the following file hierarchy:

```
public_html_local/
   applications/

   assets/
      css/
          styles.css
          ...
      js/
          jquery.js
          ...
      images/
          banner.jpg
          ...

   system/
       ...
```

In my config file:

```
    $config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/public_html_local/"
```

and in my pages, I access my CSS files as follows:

```
<base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">
<link href="assets/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

For me, I found it easier to keep my CSS files outside of the application folder.

In your case, you might expect the path to your CSS files to be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
      href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>applications/assets/styles.css" />
```

However, if you try to access the CSS file from your local server using that 
URI, it probably won't work unless you changed the `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 3):

1-If you are not using .htaccess and you did not removed your index.php file than put index.php inside the path to you css file.

2-If you used .htaccess and removed your index.php than put your css folder name inside your
.htaccess file that way it should be accessable. and my links are working fine here is
and example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define url in you constant.php
paste following code in public_html_local/application/config/constants.php

```
define('URL','http://YOUR-HOST/APPLICATION-FOLDER/');

define('CSS',URL.'assets/css/');//make a new folder named as assets if you want css sources
```

now simply use following to use stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo(CSS.'simplereflect.css'); ?>">
```