# Access Forbidden To view image file located in Codeigniter view foldr

Tags: image, codeigniter

I have the following structure,

```
root folder
--- application
    --admin
        --controllers
        --models
        --views
           --newsletter
             --images
             --screenshot.png
             --index.php
--- system
---
---
---
```

as u can see there is a png file inside  `application/admin/views/newsletter/`

when i am using this img src

application/admin/views/newsletter/screenshot.png" />

i see the image as broken link

but when i paste the address of the image in the addess bar of the browser, it says

```
"Permission Denied"
```

how can i make the image be seen, without changing the file structure..

Answer (score 1):

That's because any direct access to `application` folder is blocked by `Deny from all` rule in `application/.htaccess` file *(by default)*. If you remove that, it would work.

But, it's better to put all public files out of `application` folder. You could create a folder like `public` or `assets` beside `index.php` file and put all public files inside that.

And if you're using rewrite rules to remove `/index.php/` from URLs, consider adding a condition (as the example below) if you don't want them to be treated by `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public)
                           # Add your files/folders --^
```

Then the `src` would be something like: `base_url().'public/newsletter/screenshot.png'`.