# Images are not appeared in pages other than default URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

All the Images of the website doesn't appear.
If I access the default url, specified in config file, under the `base_url`, all the images have shown.
But when I access this url (`127.0.0.1/dcm/Controller/Index`), not even a single image is retrieved.
I think it's a path problem, but I can't figure it out properly.

Here's my root folder structure (I'll try to make it understandable):

```
css
dcmapp -> Here I have my views
dcmsys
htmlconstants -> Here are my header and footer, common in all pages
Images -> Here are all the website images
Scripts
```

For example, in my `header.php` in `htmlconstants` folder, I have this code, for example:

```
<a href="#"><img src="<?php base_url() ?>Images/fbic.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="Images/phone.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="Images/email.png"></a>
```

As you can see in code, I'm trying to use a `base_url` function to see if I can get the full path till the image, with no success.
In my Views, the same thing.

Comment: Hey Hashem Qolami, thank you for your edition. I forgot something and the text doesn't look as I expected. Thanks!

Comment: Show the source code from the browser, or use devtools/firebug to see which image urls is the browser trying to retrieve.

Comment: Have you altered the default CI's directory structure? Where's the `index.php` file? As a side-note, when it comes to assets make sure you have considered [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739397/bootstrap-files-not-load-properly-in-other-codeigniter-pages/21739689#21739689) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128740/problems-implementing-tinymce-in-codeigniter/12763788#12763788).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
<a href="#"><img src="<?php base_url() ?>Images/fbic.png"></a>
```

try this:

```
<a href="#"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Images/fbic.png"></img> </a>
```

Comment: Yes! That's it! I forgot the echo! Thanks a Lot!